# Inserting the same values of string (as a key ) in the dictionary

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-rest-framework

I was writing the python code in Django. I was facing a problem, wherein I have three fields which are optional:

```
Contact Name             Contact Number                     Contact Email
Ram                       9888812345                       *Blank*(Meaning not present)
Ram                       9888812345                        ram@gmail.com
Shyam                     8776532211                        shyam@hotmail.com
```

For this, I had written code as follows:

```
df = csv.DictReader(open(uploaded_file_path), delimiter='\t')
contact_validation = {}
for row in df:
    if not row['Contact Name']:
       row['Contact Name'] = 'Name'
    if not row['Contact Number']:
       row['Contact Number'] = 'Number'
    if not row['Contact Email']:
       row['Contact Email'] = 'Email'     
    if (row['Contact Name']+ "-" + row['Contact Number']+ "-" + row['Contact Email']) not in contact_validation.keys():                        
       contact_validation[(row['Contact Name']+ "-" + row['Contact Number']+ "-" + row['Contact Email']).strip()] = []
       contact_validation[(row['Contact Name']+ "-" + row['Contact Number']+ "-" + row['Contact Email']).strip()].append(row['Name'])
    else:
       contact_validation[(row['Contact Name']+ "-" + row['Contact Number']+ "-" + row['Contact Email']).strip()].append(row['Name'])
```

**For this, Currently I have an output as below:**

```
{'Ram-9888812345-Email': ['CRM_TestVenue_26_March_23'],
 'Ram-9888812345-ram@gmail.com': ['CRM_TestVenue_26_March_2']
 'Shyam-8776532211-shyam@hotmail.com':[Test2]}
```

**But I required the Output as follows:**

```
{'Ram-9888812345-ram@gmail.com': ['CRM_TestVenue_26_March_23','CRM_TestVenue_26_March_2'],
'Shyam-8776532211-shyam@hotmail.com':[Test2]}
```

Can anyone please suggest some piece of code or advice.? What needs to be changed or improved?

Comment: hi, can you give a sample input.

Comment: hI @Errol, I have given the sample input with all the three fields mentioned in the starting. You can ask me if something is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're wanting to combine rows that complement each other. That is, where they have the same contact name, but not a duplicate number or email. You're not including code to do that.

Since it looks like you're using pandas anyway, you could do something like

```py
contacts_missing_info = df.loc[((df['Contact Number'].isna()) | (df['Contact Email'].isna()))]
```

and use similar code to get the contacts not missing info, then combine the ones that are missing info together, then append the two dataframes and work at it that way.

---

**Edit:** Even though you're not using pandas, the idea is the same. Iterate through your object and make sure that all duplicates are combined the way you want, then execute your code.

Comment: Hi @manny. I am not using pandas . I am using django framework

Comment: I also get an error - *** AttributeError: AttributeError("DictReader instance has no attribute 'loc'",) here df = csv.DictReader(open(uploaded_file_path), delimiter='\t')

Comment: can you please suggest the same in Django python?